# git: branch not fully merged?

Tags: windows, git

I am trying to delete a branch using gitbash and i get a error about the branch not being fully merged. Using TortoiseGit i merged, switch to master, tried merging again, commit then finally pull from the master and everything is fine. Yet git reports the branch not fully merged.

I think i am missing something. What is it?

The error msg

```
 warning(_("not deleting branch '%s' that is not yet merged to\n"
      "         '%s', even though it is merged to HEAD."),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the origin (or another) branch pulls, pull from that branch even if nothing changed and you should be able to delete.

Answer (score 3):

I always get the **Branch is not fully merged** when trying to delete local feature branches after they have been merged to the master branch. No amount of pulling `master` resolves this and I must always use `git branch -D` to delete them.

This morning I decided to understand why and with the help of [GIT: Branch is Not Fully Merged](https://brianchildress.co/git-branch-not-fully-merged/) I have. Our policy is to do a squash merge when merging pull requests in Bitbucket. After reading that article I realise the "problem" is that the local feature branch contains the individual commits but the master branch contains only the one squashed commit, so Git will always report that the branch I'm trying to delete is not fully merged.

Answer (score 0):

first pull your origin master branch.once you did this you are ready to delete as your branches are fully merged now.we are getting that message cause we didnt pull changes to our master branch.